# how to debug failing document.location call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a piece of JS code which assembles a URL and then sets the document location:

```
var url = 'pi_configure_mls.cgi?token=' + params.token + '&ml_sourcekey=' + key;
document.location = url;
```

When this code runs, it simply refreshes the page (or at least shows the same page I'm on.)

The odd thing is, when I take the raw URL, and manually enter this in my console:

```
document.location = url;
```

...it works! and I'm taken to the expected page.

I've wrapped this in a try/catch, confirmed the URLs are exactly the same, and I can't tell why this would happen.

Does anyone have any tips on how to determine the cause for difference in behavior?

**UPDATE 1:**

I am logging the URL from the call and it matches what I expect:

```
pi_configure_mls.cgi?token=NEH727&ml_sourcekey=edelivery&choosetags=bc_p_2
```

I also see navigation to the new URL logged when using `window.location` and `window.top.location`:

```
Navigated to https://www.some.site.of.mine.com/pi_select.cgi
```

In looking in my python logs on the server, I don't see any hit to `pi_configure_mls_cgi` but I do see it hitting `pi_select_cgi` so I know the python is not the culprit here.

**UPDATE 2:**

Even providing the entire, absolute URL fails (in the code, not console):

```
window.top.location = 'https://www.some.site.of.mine.com/pi_configure_mls.cgi?token=NEH727&ml_sourcekey=edelivery&choosetags=bc_p_2'
```

**UPDATE 3:**

No URL in the code will work, regardless of what it is. I do see the logging statement after the location attempt in the code as if it succeeded:

```
try {
  window.top.location = 'total_garbage!!!';
  console.info('HEY WE WENT SOMEWHERE!');  //I see this logged
}
catch (e) {
  console.info('this failed!' + e);
}
```

Comment: try to `console.log` the url value to confirm it is what you want it to be and use `window.top.location=url` instead

Comment: You could use something like fiddler to see if any kind of request is going out over the wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `window.location` instead of the `document.location`

It is the recommended one to be used:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html/browsers.html#dom-location

Comment: Thanks - I'll use this going forward. Still seeing the issue, and added some update notes

Comment: Is pi_configure_mls_cgi correct? you have the dot in your URL

Comment: Yes, sorry. My cgi's are methods where the dot gets replaced with an underscore

Comment: can you try to call it directly using underscore just to be sure the issue is not there?

Comment: that's def. not the issue. All cgi's are dotted in the URL and underscored in the python code. This points out an interesting issue though: I cannot go to ANY url from the code. Updating post with this.

Comment: can you try using window.location.href = "my url" please?

Comment: same result. LMK if you wanna move this to chat

Comment: yep, I think so because I need a bit of more debug. just the last question to see if we can fix it immediately. Do you have this code inside some submit or sending data code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143539/discussion-between-jacobirr-and-quirimmo).